# Monopoly Implementing Rules

Tags: c#

I have created this Monopoly board using a linked list.

have assigned values to the squares but need to be able to add or take away these value's form the integer assigned in the player classes.

Any help or advice would be appreciated (I apologise now for the comments they have to be revised yet) the code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MonoPolyFin;

namespace MonoPolyFin
{

public class Square//Creating Squares for the board
{

    public Square next;//Declaring the Square as the next node
    public string g;//String to store the Square data

    public Square(string g)//assigning the string to g
    {
        this.g = g;
    }



    public class Board/*The Board class creating the linked list and printing it out to                        the console window*/
    {

        public Square head;//Declaring as the head 
        Square current;//and current 

        public void Add(Square s)/*The Add method for adding nodes in order to the linked list checking each time to see if the head of 
         the list is empty */
        {
            if (head == null)//if the head is empty
            {
                head = s;//the head equals the string
                current = head;//the current node is the head
            }
            else
            {
                current.next = s;//if not empty the current node is the next node
                current = current.next;//then the next
                current.next = head;//keep going round the board through the linked list
            }
        }

        public void Writeline(ref Square gamesquare)//The writeline method to print out in the console
        {
            Random r = new Random();//Creates a new object using the random method
            int n = r.Next(1, 6);//Creates a random number between 1-6
            Console.WriteLine(n);//Writes the stored number to the console
            Console.WriteLine("Player moves to " + gamesquare.g);//write the gamesquare to the console that is saved in the string g
            Console.ReadKey();//read whats in the console and throw it out


            if (n <= 1)//If the number is less than 1
            {

                head = current
                    ;//Move one positions down the list

            }
            else if (n <= 2)//If the number is less than 2
            {

                head = head.next.next;//Move two positions down the list

            }

            else if (n <= 3)//If the number is less than 3
            {

                head = head.next.next.next;//Move three positions down the list

            }
            else if (n <= 4)//If the number is less than 4
            {

                head = head.next.next.next.next;//Move four positions down the list

            }
            else if (n <= 5)//If the number is less than 5
            {

                head = head.next.next.next.next.next;//Move five positions down the list

            }
            else if (n <= 6)//If the number is less than 6
            {

                head = head.next.next.next.next.next.next;//Move six positions down the list

            }
        }
    }


  public class Player1
        {

            public string Dog;
            public int Money = 2000;
            public Square position = null;

           }


  public class Player2
  {

      public string Car;
      public int Money = 2000;
      public Square position = null;

  }


  static void Main(string[] args)//Main method
        {
            int go = 200;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int strand = 220;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int trafalger_square = 220;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int leicester_square = 280;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int piccadilly = 280;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int regent_street = 300;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int oxford_street = 300;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int mayfair = 400;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int park_lane = 400;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int whitechapel = 60;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int old_kent_road = 60;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int euston = 100;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int islington = 100;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int pall_mall = 140;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int whitehall = 140;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int vine_street = 180;//Value of the square in the linked list
            int bow_strett = 180;//Value of the square in the linked list

            Board list = new Board();//constructor to create the list
            list.Add(new Square("Go Collect £" + go));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Strand £" + strand + " Black"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value
            list.Add(new Square("Trafalger Square £" + trafalger_square + " Black"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Gas"));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Leicester Square £" + leicester_square + " Aqua"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Piccadilly £" + piccadilly + " Aqua"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Card"));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Regent Street £" + regent_street + " Yellow"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Oxford £" + oxford_street + " Yellow"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Electric" ));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Mayfair £" + mayfair + " Green"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Park Lane £" + park_lane + " Green"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Jail"));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Old Kent Road £" + old_kent_road + " Blue"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Whitechapel £" + whitechapel + " Blue"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Water"));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Islington £" + islington + " Red"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Euston £" + euston + " Red"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Card"));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Pall Mall £" + pall_mall + " Pink"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Whitehall £" + whitehall + " Pink"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Phone" ));//Add to the linked list
            list.Add(new Square("Bow Street £" + bow_strett + " Brown"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 
            list.Add(new Square("Vine Street £" + vine_street + " Brown"));//Add to the linked list using the Add method also assigning the int value 

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {

                Player2 car = new Player2();
                car.position = list.head;
                Console.WriteLine("Car roles the dice and roles");
                list.Writeline(ref car.position);

                Player1 dog = new Player1();
                dog.position = list.head;
                Console.WriteLine("Dog roles the dice and roles");
                list.Writeline(ref dog.position);
            }

          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this looks like homework, you have posted a very large wall of code. Please narrow down your code to _only the code you have a question with_.

Comment: Admittedly yes it is homework, homework I've gotten so far with and despite looking for a solution myself cannot find one. I have posted the wall of code so people that are looking at the code know where I have gotten up to and can hopefully give me there advice on where to add the code I have made a query about in the above question.

Comment: Um, I'd have expected an event on the "square" triggered by landing on it, which performed an action. PS a fun part of the game is distracting the property owner, so they don't notice you've just landed on their hotel on mayfair....

Comment: I truth I'm not sure how to action an event on a node in a linked list if that's what I have to do!!!

Comment: The repetition of pieces of text like "Pall Mall" suggest that the data structures might not clearly represent the problem domain. To me it looks like there are two options: connect the current set of data structures together with strands of spaghetti, or create objects to represent the squares - maybe passing a player as an argument to a method of a square when the player lands on it. That is, that it may be easier to design a different system than to go forward from the current code.

Comment: I see a loop elsewhere in your code.  Why are you not using a loop for the movement?

Comment: ben yeah I have tried to pass an argument but as its in a linked list I can't seem to make it work correctly!!!

Comment: paddy I have a loop to move round the board and thought inserting an if else statement so that if the player landed on the Go square fir instance they increased their money from 2000 to 2200. I have tried insert the statement through out the code with a condition but have had no luck.

Comment: What is the true value of excessive down voting a question? Some people have a real problem here....! People are asking because this is the place to ask and because they are seeking help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your squares ought to consist of a type hierarchy.

Square

- Card-Draw

  - Chance
  - Community Chest
- Tax/GO
- Jail
- Ownable

  - Utility
  - Railroad
  - Colored

All of these will have a polymorphic method

```
virtual void VisitFrom(int diceRoll, Player activePlayer);
```

For example, Utility's implementation might be.

```
virtual void VisitFrom(int diceRoll, Player activePlayer)
{
    if (owner == Bank)
        activePlayer.offerProperty(this, 150);
    else if (activePlayer != owner)
        activePlayer.Pay(owner, ((otherUtility.owner == owner)? 10: 4) * diceRoll);
}
```

Oh the other hand, both players should be instances of the same class.

You need separate classes for objects with separate behavior.  Use instances when objects act alike.

Of course you also need to associate Colored instance into ColorGroups to give bonuses when the same player owns them all.

Comment: Your right, I've implemented the players in the same class (as advised) as they have the same behaviour!!! I don't know how to structure the hierarchy as the squares are part of a linked list in all truth this is my problem.

Comment: @itchebantye: The hierarchy I've shown is intended to be an inheritance hierarchy, not a data structure.  You can still link them together as a linked list.  Since the links are in the base class.